# How to retrieve user's name from Google API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm making a Google OAuth login this way:

```
let instance = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  instance.signIn({
    scope: 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
  }).then((user) => {
    this.makeGoogleLogin(user.getAuthResponse().id_token);
  });
```

I just want to get name, email, and gender.

This code works, but as Google+ API shuts down on march 7th, I don't know how to retrieve user's name.
I've looked into Google API but couldn't find.

Do you have any idea of how I can retrieve user name from Google ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the [people API.](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)  this will return the information about the currently authenticated user

```
 GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}
```

send resorcename =people/me